# High school geometry proof help

Tags: geometry

I need help with a high school geometry proof.  I think I've figured out why the prompt is true, but the proof attempt I've come up with seems very inelegant.  Is there an easier method I'm missing?

> Consider two circles with the second internally tangent to the first at point $A$ and also passing through the center of the first. Show that every chord of the first circle which has $A$ as an endpoint is bisected by the second circle.  [image]

**My attempted proof:**

Let there be any chord of the first circle which has $A$ as an endpoint.  Let the other endpoint of the chord be called $B$.

Then let the following line segments be drawn:

- A segment connecting $A$ and the first circle's center $C$;
- A segment connecting $B$ and the first circle's center $C$; and
- A segment connecting the first circle's center $C$ with the point $I$ where the chord intersects the second circle.

Segments $AC$ and $BC$ are the same length because they both represent the radius of the first circle.

We have two right triangles $ACI$ and $BCI$.  Since the two hypotenuses $AC$ and $BC$ are the same length and the two heights $CI$ are the same length, then the two bases $AI$ and $BI$ must also be the same length.  Since $AI$ is half the length of the chord, the second circle bisects the chord.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "We have two right triangles" does not root in something we know (without proof), assuming this immediately leads to establishing the claim.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Would it be enough to reference the theorem stating that any triangle inscribed in a circle is a right triangle?

Comment: This is not true. Any triangle could be circumscribed

Comment: For me, the proof is good. But the theorem is: any triangle inscribed in a circle *with one edge being its diameter* is a right triangle

Comment: So $AC$ should be established being a diameter of the smaller circle

Comment: I think that's an OK proof, but you ought (or it would have been nicer) to put the points $C$ and $I$ in the figure along with th etriangles $ACI$ and $BCI$.

Comment: @dEmigOd what did you just call me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another proof is to take the center of the circles being $C$ (the bigger), $D$ the smaller, the intersection point $I$ for the bigger circle and $J$ for the smaller.

We have that the triangles $ADJ$ and $ACI$ are similar since they have congruent angles (which is because they are isosceles and sharing an angle (of the leg). Also we have that $AD$ is half of $AC$ which implies that $AJ$ is half of $AI$.

We know that $D$ is on $AC$ because if it weren't we would have that $ADC$ would form a proper triangle and we would have that the smaller triangle doesn't tangent the larger. We also have that $D$ is the midpoint or otherwise the smaller circle wouldn't pass through $C$.

Comment: I have posted a solution using 3D.

Answer (score 19):

Another proof:
Since both CI and BD are perpendicular to AB, CI is parallel to BD.
The fact that C is the midpoint of AD implies that I is the midpoint of AB.

[image]

Comment: How do you know $CI \bot AC$?

Comment: @dEmigOd That's a known fact since $AC$ and $AD$ are diameters of respective circle. But you don't actually need to know that since you can use similar triangles instead.

Comment: The fact is known if $AC$ is a diameter, how do you know it?

Comment: @dEmigOd Yes, but that's rather obvious. If it weren't we would be able to form a triangle $ACM$ with the midpoint of the smaller circle showing that it doesn't tangent the larger.

Comment: @dEmigOd, You could consider a tangent to both circles at A. Because the angle between a tangent and a chord [AC] equals the angle subtended by that chord [AC] in the alternate segment (angle AIC), and the angle between a tangent and diameter [AD] is 90 degrees, therefore angle AIC is 90.

Answer (score 9):

From the tangency point $A$, blow up the small circle such that $$\text{The small circle} \rightarrow ^{\text{gets mapped to}} \text{The circle twice as big}$$

Since the dilation is of factor two, QED.

Though what I've said is a mere restatement of what others said before, the idea of dilation, called *Homothety* in general is an useful tool for Eucledian Geometry (check eg. the proof of the existence of Nine Point circle)

Comment: [+1] Your solution is the most "economical" in thought and words. I have given another one that could as well been plainly described in terms of (3D) homothety !

Answer (score 2):

I think next two facts give some hints.

1. In a circle chords, based on the same length arcs are of the same length
2. Arcs of the same angle are proportional to circle radius.

This immediately gives you $2AI=AB$, since those are chords on the arcs of the same angle in circles with radius ratio of $1:2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algebraic way. Let $r$ be the radius of the small circle and $R$ be the radius of the big circle. It's obvious that $R=2r$. Now, let $AB$ be the chord of the small circle and $AC$ be the chord of the big circle. Let point $A$ be the center of coordinate $(0,0)$, point $B(x_1,y_1)$, and point $C(x_2,y_2)$. The equation of small circle is
\begin{align}
x_1^2+(y_1-r)^2&=r^2\\
x_1^2+y_1^2&=2ry_1\tag1
\end{align}
The equation of big circle is
\begin{align}
x_2^2+(y_2-2r)^2&=4r^2\\
x_2^2+y_2^2&=4ry_2\tag2
\end{align}
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $AB^2=2ry_1$ and $AC^2=4ry_2$. Then
$$\frac{AB}{AC}=\sqrt{\frac{y_1}{2y_2}}$$
It's easily noticed that $\frac{y_1}{y_2}=\frac{1}{2}$, hence
$$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I hope you won't mind if I ask you where do you share links of question?? You have got multiple booster and publicist badges.

Comment: I'm sorta popular in my country. Haha... Kidding, I use Quora.

Comment: Are you again nominating yourself in this election? I read you meta post where you nominated yourself in 2014 elections, sadly you weren't selected then but this time maybe you have a better luck. Nomination process is under way.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I'm not interested anymore since I'm busy with college stuff. Besides, I don't think I'm qualified enough.

Answer (score 0):

One can use a trick that works rather often in 2D geometry, i.e., viewing it at as a 3D issue (see figure below).

Consider the big circle as being in a certain base plane. Let $A$ be the point of tangency of the two circles. Then consider the whole figure as the projection of a certain cone that is described in this way:

- apex $S$ is on the vertical axis issued from point $A$, at height $z=2$.
- it is cutted by plane $z=1$ along a "copy"  of the small circle, that will be orthogonally projected onto the small circle.
- its generatrices are obtained by joining the apex $S$ to the generic point $M$ of the big base circle, with midpoint $M'$ situated on the copy of the small circle (for a clear reason of proportionnality: consider right triangle $SAM$).

As projections preserve the ratio of aligned points, we will still have $AM''=M''M$ ($M''$ denoting the vertical projection of $M'$).

[image]